# npm / angular issue: Could not resolve module @angular/core

Tags: angular

Out of the blue after restarting my computer, my project started giving this error while running npm run start. I have uninstalled/reinstalled node, deleted the node modules, reinstalled angular-cli, run npm install several times and still I get the same error. I can see that the @angular folder is there and inside it there is the core folder.

I have checked threads where people had similar problems and nothing really helped.  The information on this error seems meagre with an exception or two.

Has anybody faced this problem before?

[image]

**packages.json**

```
{
  "name": "ag-grid-demo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.1",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^20.0.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^20.0.0",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^20.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you check your package json file?

Comment: @MCMatan: I added it in my post. I don't know what I should look at there. Do you see something wrong in it?

Comment: What's the webpack config look like, since that's what's failing here?

Comment: Your package json is installing cli version 1.6.1. However, angular packages version is ^5.0.0. Npm is installing higher version of angular packages (probably 7). Fix your versions or use ~5.0.0. It will solve your issue.

Comment: @AkankshaGaur: Thank you. The problem was releated to the tsconfig.json which got corrupted for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem. I didn't need to touch my packages at all. My tsconfig.json was corrupt for some weird reason. I restored it, removed the node_modules, deleted package-lock.json and run

`npm install`